# keyboard appears only only once

Tags: uiviewcontroller, keyboard, notifications

I added a UISearchBar to a UIViewController programmatically, In the method where I add it to the view I wrote `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` and in both methods `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` and `hideKeyboard`i have `[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder]`

Also my code handles these two notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

I was expecting to see the keyboard every time the searchBar gets focus (user taps on it) but the result is: the keyboard appears only the first time I perform a search, after that the carriage is blinking in the field (it got focus, but the keyboard doesn't reappear)

any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking to have a normal behavior of keyboard, when the user enters the search text field the keyboard should appear and when he is done to disappear, in my case the keyboard appears only once

Comment: Add some more code.This is not enough to solve the problem

Comment: is there somewhere in code you add `resignFirstResponder` comment it and try again

Comment: I did try it, without resignFirstResponder the keyboard stays in show mode and I need it to hide once I'm done with the search